# Magento 2 Fotorama - Customise product gallery thumbnail scroll

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, fotorama-slider, fotorama

I currently have the basic Fotorama settings but I'm hoping to change those to have three thumbnails showing at a time.
When I click through using the large view next arrow, the thumbnail container will then scroll to the next three and vice versa.

I've used flexbox to override the default CSS to now only show three thumbnails with some margin in-between. It's looking great BUT the thumbnail container doesn't scroll till it hits the fifth thumbnail. 
It looks like javascript is calculating and injecting the transform settings

```
x axis after the first scroll point - transform: translate3d(-586px, 0px, 0px);
```

Using my child theme, how can I edit/override this (when to scroll) setting or the transform calculation?